# Static variable initialization using new gives a code hazard

Tags: c#, constructor, static, static-members, static-constructor

I am working on some code which is something like this:

```
class A
{
   static SomeClass a = new Someclass("asfae");  
}
```

Someclass contains the required constructor.
The code for this compiles fine without any warning. But I get a code hazard in system:

> "The Someclass ctor has been called from static constructor and/or
>   static initialiser"

This code hazard part of system just to make it better by warning about possible flaws in the system or if system can get into bad state because of this. 
I read somewhere on the web that static constructor/initialiser can get into deadlock in c# if they wait for a thread to finish. Does that have something to do with this?

I need to get rid of this warning how can i do this.
I can't make the member unstatic as it's used by a static function.
What should I do in this case , Need help.

Comment: What's the purpose of that static field ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could hide it behind a property and initialize it on first use (not thread-safe);

```
class A
{
    static SomeClass aField;

    static SomeClass aProperty
    {
        get
        {
           if (aField == null) { aField = new Someclass("asfae"); }
           return aField;
        }
    }
}
```

or use Lazy (thread-safe):

```
class A
{
    static Lazy<SomeClass> a = new Lazy<SomeClass>(() => new Someclass("asfae"));
}
```

...or this very verbose thread safe version :)

```
class A
{
    static SomeClass aField;

    static object aFieldLock = new object();

    static SomeClass aProperty
    {
        get
        {
           lock (aFieldLock)
           {
               if (aField == null) { aField = new Someclass("asfae"); }
               return aField;
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: using .net3.5 lazy is not supported and don't want to do a non thread safe solution.

Answer (score 0):

By initialising it as a static field, it behaves as it would in a static constructor, i.e. it probably gets initialised the first time an instance of your class is instantiated, but might happen earlier. If you want more control over exactly when the field is initialised, you could use `Lazy<T>`, e.g.:

```
{
   static Lazy<SomeClass> a = new Lazy<SomeClass>(() => new Someclass("asfae"));  
}
```

This way, you know that the initialisation of SomeClass will only happen the first time the field is accessed and its `Value` property called.

Answer (score 0):

I think to understand your problem you need to know the difference between static constructors and type initializers, there is a great article from Jon Skeet about this issue:

http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Beforefieldinit.aspx

The point is that following constructions are not the same, and there are difference in the behavior:

```
class Test
{
    static object o = new object();
}

class Test
{
    static object o;

    static Test()
    {
        o = new object();
    }
}
```

In any case, you could try to create a static constructor for your class to be able to have more control on this initialization, and maybe the warning will disappear.

If the member is only used by a static method, and only by this one, I would recommend you to put it in the scope if this static method and not as class member.

Comment: The member is used by other methods also some of which are not static.

Comment: @grv in this case you can only use the Lazy class (I use it quite often as well) or the static constructor which is faster and also quite secure and threading safe.

Comment: I am using .net 3.5 so using lazy is not an option as it's not supported and I tried static constructor and i am still getting the warning. Any other idea?

Comment: Since you are using a static member you're running some risks, I would understand this warning as a hint, but this doesn't mean that your code is wrong. If you need this static member and you know how to work with it, it doesn't have to harm your application. Is your app multithreaded? If is not multithreaded you don't have to worry about this.